# Add spaces after numbers

Tags: javascript, html

```
<select id="mySelect">
   <option>140 AAA</option>
   <option>141 BBB</option>
   <option>140 CCC</option>
   <option>140 EEE</option>
</select>
```

I want to add a few spaces after numbers with JavaScript.

**Desired output**

```
<select id="mySelect">
   <option>140   AAA</option>
   <option>141   BBB</option>
   <option>140   CCC</option>
   <option>140   EEE</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I also like, [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553)

Comment: @Andrew this is not a personal research, it's a task, and I've got problem with that task!!!!

Comment: @emilan: It's generally expected that you show some effort before asking questions. What have you tried so far, and what specifically didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method feels a bit, I dunno, icky. Howeve it's the first thing I can come up with in a pure JavaScript sense. Change the `10` to however many spaces you would like.

```
var selectEl = document.getElementById("mySelect");
for ( var i = 0; i < selectEl.options.length; i++ ) {
  var opt = selectEl.options[i];
  opt.innerHTML = opt.innerHTML.replace( /\s/, Array(10).join('&nbsp;') );
}
```

Comment: Prefer innerText over innerHTML. Elegant solution. Most probably a concept of onDOMContentLoaded event outside context of this question is assumed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a padded string to be output for a max length property or do you just need it for formatting and visuals? you can use the padding feature on either side of the string.

Something like this:

" " + day + " " would add a space on each side of value of day in string.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for more padding between the numbers and letters try a non-breaking space. It will show as whitespace in HTML.

```
<option>140 &nbsp;&nbsp; EEE</option>
```

If you insist on using javascript, try using jquery to loop through the options and adjust them

```
$('#mySelect > option').each (function ()
    {
    $(this).text ().replace (' ', ' &nbsp; '); 
    });
```

I haven't tested that, but you get the idea.

Comment: Added a javascript example using jQuery

Comment: This looks to be correct solution. One adjustment please, the second argument of replace should be two or three nbsp or whitespace.